# With or without reset() when getting the last key/value from array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm simply trying to get the **last** key/value from the array which is **5**. I have two versions but want to know which is the safest version. So far they both worked.

Thanks in advance.

**VER 1) Without reset()**

```
$url = "host.com/admin/product/11/sort/2/view/limit/10/result/5";
$parts = explode('/', $url);
$resultID = end($parts);
echo $resultID;
```

**VER 2) With reset()**

```
$url = "host.com/admin/product/11/sort/2/view/limit/10/result/5";
$parts = explode('/', $url);
reset($parts);
$resultID = end($parts);
echo $resultID;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `reset` is completely useless here. `end` will go to the end of the array in any case.